# IIB - Proper/Standard Way To Set HTTP Request Base URL For Different Environments

Tags: soa, esb

We are trying to implement our product with SOA and currently using IBM Integration Bus v9 as our ESB.

We have 3 different environments (Sets of servers used for different purposes) that we deploy our product on:

- **development:** Used during the testing and development process
- **customer test:** More stable builds for customer's approval before going for the main release
- **main/production:** This is the final thing.

The challenge we have encountered: Setting Base URL for HTTP nodes of our message flows for different environments; without compromising the DRY principle!

It seems that it's only possible to set the whole URL at once in HTTP Request nodes with the *mqsiapplybaroverride* command. The problem is that multiple resources can be exposed from a single server and thus have a common base URL.

Using **UDP** seems to be a promising approach. We can set base URL for each of our services in a UDP and build HTTP Request URLs in compute nodes just before the HTTP Request node using the UDP. Then the UDPs can be overrided with the *mqsiapplybaroverride*... Problem? It seems that UDPs don't have a scope of more than a single message flow... so anytime I want to call a resource from a server I have to define a UDP for that message flow or the BAR override won't affect the base URL for that message flow... This would lead to base URLs being repeated in each message flow... DRY applies.

This should be a common problem in a typical SOA application... So is there any better way to solve it? Anything like JNDI feature in typical Java EE Containers?

IIB v10.0.0.6 seems to have introduced a RestRequest node which provides Base URL setting capability... Unfortunately, we don't have that luxury for the time being.

Comment: DRY is nice and all, but in certain cases I think it's better to explicitly set parameters, and I think in this case it would be cleaner to just set the whole URL for each of your HTTP nodes. By setting the URLs from code you just introduce possible bugs, and in general compicate a simple configuration.

Comment: What about different environments? Edit all the Request URLs for each environment?... Doesn't sound like a lot of fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution is to set baseUrl in database for each environment and set value as bellow:

```
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.REST.Request.BaseURL = GetCachedOrFromDB('custom_service_baseUrl');
```

GetCachedOrFromDB -> define function to get value from cache or db (if not in cache)
'custom_service_baseUrl' - > define property as key in settings table for each environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **user defined configurable service** to achieve this.

You can read and set URL from configurable service using a java compute node or using a mapping node and custom java.

Comment: Thank you I'll check this one out